# Octokit - starring method

Tags: .net, github-api, octokit, octokit.net

Is there a native method on Octokit that allows starring a repo?

Been looking around ex on client.Repositories and can not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your tags I assume you are talking about [Oktokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net)

The documentation doesn't list independent API calls but I was able to detect this feature looking at the source:

Check [IObservableStarredClient.cs](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/Octokit.Reactive/Clients/IObservableStarredClient.cs#L218-L224):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Stars a repository for the authenticated user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="owner">The owner of the repository to star</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name of the repository to star</param>
    /// <returns>A <c>bool</c> representing the success of starring</returns>
    IObservable<bool> StarRepo(string owner, string name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can star a repository by the following method

```
await client.Activity.Starring.StarRepo(repo.Owner.Login, repo.Name);
```

The method will return bool indicating whether repository was starred successfully or not.